# What is the correct approach of writing Espresso UI Test for nested RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-espresso, nestedrecyclerview

What is the correct way of writing UI Test for Nested RecyclerViews using Espresso

Element structure is

```
 - RecyclerView1
    - TextView1
    - RecyclerView2
        - TextView2
```

Requirement is to iterate over each RecyclerView items and validate `isDisplayed()`

Comment: RecyclerView1 is Vertical view and RecyclerView2 is horizontal

Answer (score 0):

It depends on id of elements of your RecyclerViews, but for most of cases enough find elements by 2 matchers. First of all find element by `withId` and then find your element by `withText` matcher. If text of textViews are equals then you can select textView which you need by `withIndex` matcher. `withIndex` works perfectly corner cases like recycler view with identical elements